# UIScrollView zooming only to the size of UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I have `UIScrollView` in which `UIImageView` is held like on the screenshot:

[image: View hierarchy]

My problem appears when I zoom and instead of being able to scroll only in the area of my image (subview of scroll view) I'm able to scroll around the original size so I get a lot of white space around my image which isn't what I want. You can see what happens on the screenshot below:

[image: Effect]

**I wonder what should I update to keep my scrolling area only the size of the image?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research, some trials and errors I've finally achieved what I was planning to do.

First of all, I wanted to use only **autolayout** with IB which sure can be done but with some effort. After some digging I've found this [technical note](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2154/_index.html) which by **"Pure Auto Layout Approach"** understands adding contraints in code but I was aiming at only IB which led me to this simple but beautiful solution called [ios-imagescroll](https://github.com/evgenyneu/ios-imagescroll). After investigating this code with joy that I've finally found solution I came with some error but only on iOS 8 devices... iOS 7 worked like charm out of the box.

I assume that due to big changes in iOS 8 autolayout is more strict and you must be 100% sure what you want to accomplish. It turned out that this slight change **MATTERS on iOS 8**:

[image] [image]

Of course, this bug, fix (call it whatever you like) was fixed by experimenting with everything but I guess that `UIScrollView`'s content view (in that case `UIImageView`) must be the first item in constraint.

Answer (score 0):

```
    [yourScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(yourScrollView.size.width, yourImage.frame.origin.y + yourImage.frame.size.height+35 )]; //let's say just 35 ...
```

yourImage may have x,y origins like (0,0) [I see a lot of space above it, so I assume you have set other values for x,y]

Comment: Yes, you're right but only if this hierarchy is created without autolayout! But I want to achieve this with autolayout...